# pubnub.publish message string format

Tags: iot, pubnub

I tried to publish message writing code,

```
MyService.pubnub.publish().channel("birdpeek").message("{"rlysw":{"0":1}}").async(new PNCallback<PNPublishResult>()
```

But the android returns error by turning red
[image]

I even put \" and it turns green out of blue but problem is what got on pubnub console the message is `Sat Nov 12 2016 18:57:40:592 : <birdpeek> "{\"rlysw\":{\"0\":1}}"`.
What proper statement i should have inserted i need advise. And here's the json object i wanna publish,

```
{"rlysw":{"1":0}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just publish the json object. The SDK will do the conversion on the hood for you. Use the following code to properly build the object.

```
Map<String, Map<String, Object>> payload = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Object> innerPayload = new HashMap<>();
innerPayload.put("0", 1);
payload.put("rlysw", innerPayload);
```

Eric

Comment: It really works. Great! Really appreciate it Eric. Thx for the attention. BTW I can't find this tips stated in any of the doc write up in pubnub website and this format is highly necessary. I think you should hv others let know and have included it too.